# I made a simple Download Manager in Java, my Download Manager is able to download is unable to download large files from the net

Tags: java, download-manager

I am not able to download large files from the net ( more than 1 mb file ). However, my program is able to download those large files from the localhost. Is there anything else that i need to do to download large files? 
Here is the code snippet:

```
 try {

        //connection to the remote object referred to by the URL.
        url = new URL(urlPath);
        // connection to the Server
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // get the input stream from conn
        in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        // save the contents to a file
        raf = new RandomAccessFile("output","rw");


        byte[] buf = new byte[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
        int read;

        while( ((read = in.read(buf,0,BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) )
    {

            raf.write(buf,0,BUFFER_SIZE);
    }

    } catch ( IOException e ) {

    }
    finally {

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're ignoring how many bytes you've actually read:

```
while( ((read = in.read(buf,0,BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) )
{
    raf.write(buf,0,BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

Your `write` call *always* writes the whole buffer, even if you didn't fill it with the `read` call. You want:

```
while ((read = in.read(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)
{
    raf.write(buf, 0, read);
}
```